# Can Java Applets be dangerous?

Tags: java, security, applet, virus

So I'm currently reading the "Java A Beginners Guide 7th Edition" book. And the following sentences seemed to me that Applets could be used as virusis. Was this done?

> An Applet is a special kind of Java program that is designed to be transmitted over the Internet and automatically executed inside a Java-compatible web browser.
>
> The key feature of applets is that they execute locally...

To me it sounds like it wouldn't be hard to build in a virus into an Applet.

Comment: Java Applets are out of date. there's no point of learning about them. Most browsers (if not all) don't support them anymore

Comment: They were supposed to run in a "sandbox" that prevented them from doing nasty things to the users' machine.  However, numerous security flaws were discovered over the years.  Browser implementors got fed up and eventually started to actively block Java in the browser.  Eventually Oracle gave up too ... and deprecated and then dropped applet support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with applets is that they run automatically when you load the page. They're also so complex (compared to html or javascript) it was just to complicated to be able to meaningfully secure them. Run Automatically + Complicated to Secure + Doesn't Update Automatically = impossible to completely secure.

Regular apps are far far more dangerous to your machine than applets were. But, they don't run automatically when you visit a web page.

Desktop apps written in languages (like C or C++) where you manipulate the memory with pointers and don't automatically bounds check arrays, are much harder to write securely. Languages (like Java or C#) that don't have pointers and do automatically bounds check arrays are easier to write secure apps in.

Java includes many safewards to prevent any ill behavior, but time after time, those security features were not enough because of different bugs or design problems.

As standalone apps they are as safe or risky as any other app. Just make sure to download your app from trusted sources.

Comment: "the recommendation now is to disable Java applets in the browser" ? What browser are you using? IE 6? Browsers (most of them, the big ones definitely) don't support applets anymore. They won't work, period, unless you are still working with some ancient version.